# Tablet form design navigation: Up/down or left to right

Tags: forms, information-architecture, tablet

[image]

I'm designing a long tablet form and trying to decide on the navigation. My intuition is telling me option A in the image is the right approach. It feels like one long form on one page vs. several pages but I don't have anything to back this up. Are there any studies out there or is this something I should test both ways?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how long form is, it is good to have it clustered in steps.

I would also go with vertical to down behavior, as it is more used and popular to scroll down than swipe.

Having horizontal version would make sense if your users will use tablet in landscape mode. So you maybe can research how often is that, and how often tabet users do swipes.